# Generating set of a ring and the "empty product"

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, terminology

Given some ring $R$, a subset of elements $S$ is a "generating set" $R$ if every element in the ring can be written as a sum or difference of products of elements of $S$. Or, borrowing the LaTeX from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/942397/52694), we have that a ring $R$ is generated by $S=\{s_1,\dots, s_n\}$ iff every element of $R$ can be written in the form

$$
\pm(s_{i_{1,1}}s_{i_{1,2}}\dots s_{i_{2,1}})\pm(s_{i_{2,2}}\dots s_{i_{2,p_1}})\pm\dots\pm(s_{i_{n,1}}\dots s_{i_{n,p_n}})
$$

The question, which is also talked about in the comments of the above answer, is if the "empty product" of $1$ is allowed. If so, this would seem to suggest that $\Bbb Z$ is generated by the empty set, since everything is a sum or difference of empty products. This is kind of the ring-theoretic version of the idea that the trivial group is generated by the empty set.

Similarly, the rings $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ would also appear to be generated by the empty set (as a subset of those rings). The ring $\Bbb Z[x]$ would be generated by only $\{x\}$, as $1$ would still basically be generated as an empty product of no $x$'s (i.e. as $x^0$).

It all seems to make sense, and agrees with the alternative definition that $S$ generates $R$ iff $R$ is the smallest subring of itself (preserving $1$) that has all the elements of $S$, which is (vacuously) true of the empty set in $\Bbb Z$.

**Questions**:

1. Is this standard use of terminology when we talk about generating sets of rings?
2. If we look at "rng"s without $1$, is it then standard to omit the empty product (equivalent to looking at the smallest "subrng" containing $S$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should allow the empty product. This means the empty subset generates the [prime subring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ring), namely the subring generated by $1$. This is, as you say, consistent with the alternative definition that the subring generated by $S$ is the intersection of all subrings containing $S$.

In a non-unital ring the empty product can't be assigned a meaningful value so you should omit it, and this is, as you say, consistent with taking the intersection of all sub-non-unital-rings containing $S$.

Personally I think this is itself an argument that multiplicative identities are a fundamental part of what a ring is, and we should just never talk about non-unital rings (all examples I'm aware of can be described as ideals in other unital rings instead); see Bjorn Poonen's *[Why all rings should have a $1$](https://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ring.pdf)* for more on this.

Comment: You can always realize non-unital rings as ideals by adjoining a unit, and the category of them is equivalent to the category of augmented $\mathbb Z$-algebras. However, non-unital rings do play some role in, say, K-theory.

Comment: Yes, but that isn't necessarily the most natural way to do it. E.g. people like talking about the non-unital algebra of compactly supported continuous or smooth functions on a space or manifold; this is naturally an ideal in the unital algebra of bounded or arbitrary continuous or smooth functions. Similarly with the non-unital algebra of compact operators on a Banach space, which is naturally an ideal in the unital algebra of bounded operators.

Comment: A point of talking about non-unital algebras instead of ideals in an algebra is precisely the *independence* of choice of "ambient" rings. For example, [Gabber's criterion of henselianness](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09XI) tells us that whether a ring-ideal pair (A,I) is henselian only depends on the non-unital ring I. This is also how it is used in K-theory (e.g. pro-excision).